# sql job to write to a file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an xml datatype column in one of the tables. Is it possible to write a sql job to write the contents of that column (one file per record in the table) to a text file ?

It would be helpful if someone can point me to a link that shows how to write such a job.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [check this](http://www.simple-talk.com/code/WorkingWithFiles/spWriteStringTofile.txt), I Googled it for you.